# How to change edittext string sum to int

Tags: android

Sorry for my bad English
I want to know how to convert a mathematical sum in EditText to int
for example if I put this sum in calculator app 1+2+3+4
the EditText reads it as String not int .. so how can I convert it to int then get the sum of it.

Comment: Use Integer.valueOf(et.getText.toString());

Comment: Didn't work ..... !!!